# CodeIgniter Ajax $_Post Is Empty

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

**Relevant Javascript:**

```
var tx = $("tx"+working_row).val();
var mods = $("mods"+working_row).val();
var pos = $("pos"+working_row).val();
var startdate = $("startdate"+working_row).val();
var enddate = $("enddate"+working_row).val();
var fordx = $("4dx"+working_row).val();
var qty = $("qty"+working_row).val();
var price = $("price"+working_row).val();
var token = $.cookie("csrf_cookie_name")
var obj = {"csrf_token_name": token, "tx" : tx, "mods":mods,"pos":pos,"startdate":startdate,"enddate":enddate,"fordx":fordx,"qty":qty,"price":price };
$.post("index.php/auth/fee_schedule",obj, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

**Relevant Controller Function:**

```
function fee_schedule(){
    echo var_dump($_POST);
}
```

**Request Headers from Firebug:**

```
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost/medata/
Cookie  ci_csrf_token=4330bb2c724341c409a53acabe14e04d; ci_session=AzcHaQViV2wGLgcmB2kBNQA%2FAToHIF1%2FCj4GIwNwBToCOlNuBwxeOgEwVyENZQJwDWRTMlA2UW5ec1Y2VzRUZwQxBmZXNQFvBDJUPlI1DmYDMwcwBTNXZwZiB2AHMgFmADcBOQc7XTgKPwZiA2cFYgJgU2UHNV5lATBXIQ1lAnANZFMwUDRRbl5zVj5XIlRaBDQGNFczASUENlR0UnUOIQNtByAFbFdvBm8HdwdiATYAOAEuBzJdIgprBn4DMgVxAm5TcwdpXmIBZFc5DXwCdg0tU2RQdlELXjBWMFc3VGsEIQZyV2wBJARpVDJSNg45A3QHHgU5VywGPAc5Bz8BZQAgATUHLF08CnsGeANUBToCO1NkBzxeJAEnVyMNEAJXDX5TN1AqUWVealZ3VwVUSgQCBmZXYwFsBHNUdVJwDjkDYwd9BWZXeAZkB3wHcwFDAGoBYwdpXS4KYAYjAzkFYgJmUzoHcV4%2FATVXcA0qAlwNP1NiUHBRPV4nVj5XJlR8BHcGa1c%2BAW0EYlQ0UjcOMQNlB2EFblduBmAHbAdoAXk%3D
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  0
```

**Current Response:**

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>
```

The Post In Firebug's Net Tab is showing as Empty, and the post Variable on the server side is Empty. What's wrong with the JS call?

Thoughts?

Thanks in Advance!

**Edit** I've also tried seeing if it's in CodeIgniter's Input Class via this:

```
$data = $this->input->post();
echo var_dump(data);
```

To No Success, it's a Boolean False because the Post Data is Empty.

Comment: when the AJAX call leaves your browser, it is also shown in the Net Tab of Firebug. Does it say any post value is sent ?

Comment: No, On the Net Tab of Firebug, under the POST sub tab, it's totally blank.

Comment: ok so it's not a codeigniter issue, it's just your jQ.post that is not sent right. are you sure that your "obj" is a valid object ?

Comment: The strange part is it must be posting the object because I'm getting the null array response from the controller and CSRF is Enabled and the token is being accepted. So that data's making it to the server some how, even if firebug isn't seeing it. hence the confusion?

Comment: Nope, data is not making it to server. POST is always an array, it's a global variable of PHP. When it's empty, it's just empty, but it doesn't stop existing.

Comment: I lied, Even if I remove the CSRF token it works, which makes me wonder about that validation, but ignoring that, you're right, must be a post problem. any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Probably harmless too : you miss a ";" after the "token" var definition. When you type alert(obj) or alert(obj.startdate) everything appears normal ?

Comment: Fixed the ; and also revised the code to: 
obj = new Object();
obj={csrf_token_name: token, tx : tx, mods:mods,pos:pos,startdate:startdate,enddate:enddate,fordx:fordx,qty:qty,price:price};
alert(obj);

Still Doesn't work. Alert Says [object Object]

Comment: Verify that EACH value of your object is OK and well escaped. Unit-test each one, until the "post" content of your query shows soemthing. At this point you should be ok.

Comment: Ok, So I just figured out that the Jquery Call to get the value of the field was failing, so the variables were empty. So I've switched that to use full Javascript now and it's working, and Now I'm running into the CSRF problem. (not Allowed).

Comment: hehe ok but that is a whole different problem then :P close this question and start q new specific one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to validate your sent object to be sure that it is actually POSTing values to the request page ;)

Answer (score 0):

on codeignter you can't use gzip compression and "echo" on controller , you must use view for output

> VERY IMPORTANT: If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts. For compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called by the output class. Do not "echo" any values with compression enabled.

Comment: I assume that for debugging purpose, he's not yet emabling compression though